# Issue connecting to elastic search from logstash in input

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to import data from oracle and would like to pass one of the params of the imported data to elastic search to fetch some other details.

For ex:- If I have an Employee Id which I get from oracle db for say 100 rows , I want to pass all these 100 employee ids to elastic search and get the emp name and salary.

I am able to retrieve the data from oracle now but unable to connect to elastic search. Also I am not sure what will be a better approach to do this.
I am using log stash 2.3.3 and the elastic search log stash filter plugin.

```
 input {
       jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<dbhost>:<port>:<sid>"
        # The user we wish to execute our statement as
        jdbc_user => “user"
        jdbc_password => “pass"
        # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
        jdbc_driver_library => “<path>"
        # The name of the driver class for oracle
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        # our query
        statement => "SELECT empId, desg from Employee"
    }
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "https://xx.corp.com:9200"
        index => “empdetails”
    }
   }
   output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
   }
```

I am getting the below error due to elastic search.

A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.

Plugin: ["https://xx.corp.com:9200"], index=>"empdetails ", query=>”empId:’1001'", codec=>"UTF-8">, scan=>true, size=>1000, scroll=>"1m", docinfo=>false, docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"], ssl=>false>

Error: [401]  {:level=>:error}

Comment: I could get the above error fixed and now I am able to get the data from elastic search. But can anyone still give me any pointer on how I can pass the data from jdbc and fetch corresponding data from elastic search. I am very new to log stash , hence any info is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Updated the code as below - elasticsearch {
        ssl => true
     hosts => "xx.corp.com:9200"
     index => "empdetails"
     query => '{ "query": { "match": { "empId": "1001" } } }'
     user => "admin"
     password => "admin"
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`elasticsearch` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html) and not the [`elasticsearch` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html)

```
input {
   jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<dbhost>:<port>:<sid>"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => “user"
    jdbc_password => “pass"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => “<path>"
    # The name of the driver class for oracle
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT empId, desg from Employee"
   }
}
filter {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["xx.corp.com:9200"]
    query => "empId:%{empId}"
    user => "admin"
    password => "admin"
    sort => "empName:desc"
    fields => {
      "empName" => "empName" 
      "salary" => "salary" 
    }
  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

As a result, each record fetched via JDBC will be enriched by the corresponding data found in ES.

Comment: Thanks Val. I had figured it out and got it  changed to elastic search filter but I hit another issue where I get  "No mapping found for [@empName] in order to sort on" . The updated code in filter is filter {
 elasticsearch {
        ssl =>  "true"
     hosts => ....
     user => "admin"
     password => "admin"
     index => ....
     query => "empId: R1001"
 fields => ["@empName", "@salary"]
 sort => "@ empName:desc"
  
    }
}

Comment: What is the name of the field you want to sort on? Are you sure it's `@empName` and not simply `empName`?

Comment: empName field as stored in elastic search.

Comment: Ok then simply change this `sort => "empName:desc"`

Comment: ok yes that was the mistake.I tried replacing timestamp and missed the @. That error is not coming anymore. Any idea why I might be getting - Failed to query elasticsearch for previous event....  @lut={}>>, :error=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass>, :level=>:warn}

Comment: Yes, what specific fields to you need to get from ES?

Comment: I want to retrieve empName and salary. This is the query what I am using now   query => "empId: 1001"
fields => ["empName","salary"]
sort => "empName:desc"

Comment: You need to specify the `fields` you want to rerieve. I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot that too works now. But the placeholder for the empId does not work for me  . I am getting the error - Encountered \" \"}\" \"} \"\" at line 1, column 26.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"TO\" ...\n    <RANGE_QUOTED> ...\n    <RANGE_GOOP> ...\n    ","caused_by":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Encountered \" \"}\" \"} \"\" at line 1, column 26.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"TO\" ...\n    <RANGE_QUOTED> ...\n    <RANGE_GOOP> ...\n    "}}}}]},"status":400}>, :level=>:warn}
query => "empId:${emp_id}"

Comment: There was a typo in my answer, you need `"empId:%{empId}"` since the field in the DB is also called `empId`

Comment: There was a little mistake in my initial post. In DB the field name is emp_id and in elasticsearc the field is empId. So now I changed my query as SELECT emp_id as empId, desg from Employee. I am using the query as you have given but still the same error is coming.

Comment: Make sure to use `%{}` and not `${}` as in my initial answer.

Comment: Yes i am using query => "empId:%{empId}". The whole thing works fine if I hardcode it to a value. But fails with the dynamic value.

Comment: Can you comment out the `elasticsearch` filter and show a sample event as it comes out of the `jdbc` input? (update your question with it, please)

Comment: Sorted now. Though I have changed query as empId it is giving result as empid. So I changed the filter query and it works fine now. Huge thanks to you for helping me so much today.